A movie where a girl (a singer) take care of a young woman on her last days (>2010)
A girl takes care of a woman in terminal illness. The girl's parents visit her to complain about this job. The girl says "mom, I'm doing something good". Then the mother replies: "No. That woman is going to die. You're wasting your time, leaving the school... " Unexpectedly the sick woman is hearing their talking and, after the parents are gone, she fires the girl.
Few scenes later, she's in the hospital in a sort a comma state. Someone brings a document where the sick woman gives to the fired girl, all the authority in taking decisions about where to take the ill woman in this situation. Against the woman's mother will, the girl take the ill woman to her house where she dies short later.
I remember, specially, the ending part where the girl is singing on a stage. 
I remember, specially, that part because she is a very good singer.   
It is a recent movie. Most probably after 2010. 

You're Not You (2014)
From Wikipedia:


Kate (Hilary Swank), a classical pianist is diagnosed with ALS. Her husband Evan (Josh Duhamel) tries to find someone to take care of his
    wife. Bec (Emmy Rossum) – a college student – applies for the job
    despite her lack of experience. Kate sees something special in Bec and
    wants to have her as her caregiver to help her with everyday things
    like taking a shower. Eventually Kate splits up with Evan due to his
    brief affair, as well as her wanting to not be invisible. She thinks
    that she has become the person in his life holding him back. She takes
    off with Bec and stays the night. In the morning she tells Bec to take
    her to an assisted living home, but Bec refuses to leave her there.
    Instead they visit Evan at his office so Kate can tell him she doesn't
    want to be with him anymore.

Bec and Kate have a couple of adventures, including going to a club,
  meeting another couple where the wife has ALS, and trying "herbal
  therapy." They eventually go to a party for Kate's friend's daughter.
  Kate asks to hold the baby, but has a coughing fit and almost drops
  the baby. While Bec is taking care of Kate inside Evan appears and
  Kate has Bec tell him that the reason she wanted him to leave was not
  because of the affair. She was just tired of being invisible. The wife
  from the couple they met earlier has complication due to her condition
  and is hospitalized. It scares Kate when she sees what happens
  eventually to ALS patients. Bec briefly talks to Kate's "best friends"
  who tell her to tell Kate that they love her, miss her, and are here
  for her. Evan visits the house again, but Kate and Bec turn him away
  again. Bec's parents visit for Christmas and a conversation with her
  Mom that is heard over the monitor by Kate causes Kate to fire Bec
  because she believes that her illness is ruining Bec's life like it
  did with Evan.
Kate goes to her parents' house and attends a Christmas party with
  Evan, hinting that they are together again. Eventually, Bec receives
  news that Marilyn, the other ALS patient they met, has died. She drops
  off a letter with Evan for Kate that Marilyn sent to some of her
  friends. Kate becomes hospitalized shortly after and it is discovered
  that Bec was given medical authority over Kate. Even though Kate's
  mother begs her to put Kate on a ventilator, Bec refuses and instead
  takes her home with Evan. Bec helps Kate play her favorite Chopin
  piece on the piano again. After Evan professes his love for her, Kate
  and Bec lie in bed, where Kate makes Bec promise not to call for help
  tonight and to find someone for herself who can see her. Bec agrees,
  on the condition that Kate promises to accept a compliment. And Bec
  thanks her for the Manolos they shared, teaching her how to cook, and
  letting her experience this with Kate and not letting her mess up this
  job. Kate dies that night and Bec, unable to stay in the other room,
  holds her while she takes her last breaths. The movie ends with Bec
  finally meeting with Will, a nice boy who has been pursuing her, and
  performing at the club without suffering from stage fright.


You're welcome! I like watching movies : )

@pori You seem to be an expert in finding movies and TV shows. Kindly try identifying this one.

@AJ I'm trying to find : )
